What is the model of a group (from Group Theory) from the perspective of Type Theory?
Given that a group is a set with a binary operation, how would you define a group in Type Theory?
I am starting with code sort of like this:
structure group
  head type

  link set, like set, have type
  link operation, like binary-operation, have type
  link identity, like type
  link inverse, like unary-operation, have type

  # Closure under the group operation
  assume set-closure
    head type, have type
    have set
    have operation

  # Associativity of the group operation
  assume set-associativity
    head type, have type
    have set
    have operation

  # Existence of the identity element
  assume set-identity-element
    head type, have type
    have set
    have operation
    have identity

  # Existence of inverses
  assume set-inverse-element
    head type, have type
    have set
    have operation
    have identity
    have inverse

property set-associativity
  head type

  take set, like set, have type
  take operation, like binary-operation, have type

  all a, b, c, in set
    assert associativity
      head type, have type
      have a
      have b
      have c
      have operation

property associativity
  head type

  take a, like type
  take b, like type
  take c, like type
  take operation, like binary-operation, have type

  assert left-associativity
    head type, have type
    have a
    have b
    have c
    have operation
  assert right-associativity
    head type, have type
    have a
    have b
    have c
    have operation

property right-associativity
  head type

  take a, like type
  take b, like type
  take c, like type
  take operation, like binary-operation, have type

  assert equal
    do operation
      do operation
        item a
        item b
      item c
    do operation
      item a
      do operation
        item b
        item c

# ...

In traditional programming language syntax, this might be like:
type Group<ElementType> = {
  set: Set<ElementType>
  operation: BinaryOperation<ElementType>
}

But either way, in my case structure is a type definition, the head type means it takes a type parameter (in this case for the element of the set type), the link are the properties of the group, and the assume are the axioms. The property defines a property, etc..
But I'm wondering, do I need the set object, when defining a group as a type? Or is the head type (the element type) enough to define the set, coming at this from type theory?
Basically, sets seem to be replaced by types in type theory, but at the same time sets can be literally collections of objects, so there is the "small set" (collections of objects) and "large set" (equivalent to types with instances of that type being the set elements).
How would you model groups in type theory? What should I change or get rid of?
I like the idea of types as the foundation of mathematics, but all of quantum mechanics relies on group theory rather than type theory, so I'm unsure how to unite the two atm.

Perhaps you might find the follwing introduction to formalising groups in the Lean proof assistant to be helpful? "Group Theory in Lean", by Mitchell Rowett [PDF]

See here for a definition of groups in Agda. I'm not sure what your actual question is.
